# AWS ElasticSearch domain creation permission

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-iam, aws-elasticsearch

I tried to give permission required to create an ES domain in AWS to an IAM account but I couldn't find any existing policy to attach except AdministratorAccess. Is there a custom policy or something I can assign to the IAM account? I searched the web but couldn't find anything helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon ES supports three types of access policies:

1. Resource-based Policies
2. Identity-based Policies
3. IP-based Policies

To get detailed information, about how to **create your own custom policies** you can go through these official documentation :

[Identity and Access Management in Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html)

[Fine-Grained Access Control in Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/fgac.html)

To configure access policies, you also get some templates, modifying which you can create your own policies.

[image]

You can create IP-based restrictions, you can restrict Amazon ES endpoint access to certain AWS accounts or users

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "111.222.333.444/32"
          ]
        }
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:123456789012:domain/mydomain/*"
    }
  ]
```

To know more about **How to Control Access to Your Amazon Elasticsearch Service Domain** [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-your-amazon-elasticsearch-service-domain/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I am looking for is not access permission but permission to create an ElasticSearch domain. With a root account, I can create one but I want to assign this permission to a non-root account