# AWS ElasticSearch Request not giving response in Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, postman, aws-elasticsearch

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html

I am following above document, to connect to my AWS Elastic Search via Postman.

What I want to achieve sent request & get the response.

I put all things related Authentication as well, still it is giving timeout error.

It is giving error `'Could not get any response'`.

My Postman settings related to SSL is also correct

Sample URL :

```
https://vpc-abc-yqb7jfwa6tw6ebwzphynyfvaka.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com/elasticsearch_index/_search?source={"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"multi_match":{"query":"abc","fields":["name.suggestion"],"fuzziness":1}}]}},"size":10,"_source":["name"],"highlight":{"fields":{"name.suggestion":{}},"pre_tags":["\u003Cem\u003E"],"post_tags":["\u003C\/em\u003E"]}}&source_content_type=application/json
```

[image]

Comment: Your ES domain is in the vpc. How did you enable access to it?

Comment: Via security group & allowing port to it @Marcin

Answer (score 1):

Since your ES domain is in the VPC, you **can't access if from the internet**. The use of security groups and "allowing port" is unfortunately not enough.

The following is written in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-vpc.html):

> If you try to access the endpoint in a web browser, however, you might find that the **request times out**. To perform even basic GET requests, your computer must be able to connect to the VPC. This connection often takes the form of a **VPN, managed network, or proxy server**.

Some options to consider are:

- Setup a bastion host in the VPC in its public subnet, and **ssh tunnel** connection from the ES to your local mac through the bastion host. This would be the easiest ad-hoc proxy solution mentioned in the docs.
- Accessing the EC directly from the bastion host (e.g. remote desktop)
- Setting up a proxy server to proxy all requests from the internet into the ES.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So I can't connect from my local macbook to vpc?.

Comment: @AnkitShah Not directly. You can setup a bastion host in the VPC, and `ssh tunnel` connection from the ES to your local mac through the bastion host. This would be the easiest ad-hoc  **proxy** solution mentioned in the docs. Alternatively, query the ES domain from the bastion host itself (e.g. setup remote destop).

Answer (score 0):

For creating and managing ES domain you can refer this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createupdatedomains.html).

**While creating ES domain in the Network configuration section, you can choose either VPC access or Public access. If you select public access, you can secure your domain with an access policy that only allows specific users or IP addresses to access the domain.**

To know more about access policies, you can refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61971342/10348758).

So, if you create your ES domain outside VPC, in public access you can easily send request and get response through postman, **without adding any Authorization**.

The `endpoint` in the url, is the `endpoint` that is generated when you have created your ES domain.

**To create an index**

[image]

**For adding data into the index**

[image]

**Get API to get the mapping of index created**

[image]

**Now, you can check it from your AWS console, that this index is created in the ES domain**

[image]